# Difference between pointer[0] and *pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

So I have the following array `fib_sequence` in C passed to a function as `*fib_sequence[]`.

My function segfaults when I access an element by doing:

```
*fib_sequence[i]
```

However it works when I do:

```
fib_sequence[0][i]
```

Am I going insane or are these not equivalent?

For reference here is the entire function, it failed when assigned to index 1 *only*.

**Segfault function**

```
void fib(int *fib_sequence[], int count) {
    *fib_sequence = malloc(sizeof(int[count]));

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            *fib_sequence[i] = 0;

        } else if (i == 1) {
            *fib_sequence[i] = 1;

        } else if (i >= 2) {
            *fib_sequence[i] = *fib_sequence[i-2] + *fib_sequence[i-1];
        }
    }
}
```

**Working Function**

```
void fib(int *fib_sequence[], int count) {
    *fib_sequence = malloc(sizeof(int[count]));

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            fib_sequence[0][i] = 0;

        } else if (i == 1) {
            fib_sequence[0][i] = 1;

        } else if (i >= 2) {
            fib_sequence[0][i] = fib_sequence[0][i-2] + fib_sequence[0][i-1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small note: In some cases `*p` is not equivalent to `p[0]`, though it's always equivalent to `*(p + 0)` (note the pointer arithmetic here).

Comment: Try ``(*fibSequence)[0]``.

Comment: @iBug: "*In some cases *p is not equivalent to p[0]*" in which cases, please?

Comment: @alk see the end of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54319099/5958455) below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not equivalent, because postfix operators have a higher precedence than unary. This means that `*fib_sequence[i]` actually means `*(fib_sequence[i])`. Then by the equivalence of `*(E)` and `(E)[0]` that you understand correctly, that expression means `(fib_sequence[i])[0]`, from which we can drop the unnecessary parentheses to get `fib_sequence[i][0]`.

Remember postfix versus unary/prefix: `*E`, `++E`, `&E` and others are all unary operators. `E(...)`, `E[]`, `E->memb`, `E.memb` are postfix.

All unary and postfix can be clumped together as one. When postfix is combined with postfix, it's clear: they go in one direction, from the root expression on the left, toward the right: `E[i]->foo.memb(arg)[blah]`. The precedence is all the same and the associativity can obviously only be left to right.

When unaries are combined, same thing in the opposite direction: `sizeof (T) &*++E`. The precedence is all the same, and the associativity is right-to-left. All of these are higher than the various binary operators.

If we put these two together, we hardly have to think:

```
sizeof (T) &*++E[i]->foo.memb(arg)[blah]
```

Once we scan past the unary operators to find the `E`, the precedence situation is simply this:

```
sizeof (T) &*++ ( E[i]->foo.memb(arg)[blah] )
                ^---------------------------^
```

the postfix cruft all has higher precedence than the unary cruft.

Postfixes have **the** highest precedence, followed by unaries, then everything else.

Answer (score 2):

You want to be aware that unary `*` and `[]` has different "precedence", and your expression

```
*foo[1]
```

is actually parsed as

```
*(foo[1])
```

You need to parenthesize your "preference" so it functions correctly:

```
(*foo)[1]
```

---

On a side note: In some cases `*p` is not equivalent to `p[0]`, though it's always equivalent to `*(p + 0)` (note the pointer arithmetic here).

Therefore, you may find `p[0]` refuses to compile when `p` is a function pointer, because it cannot participate in pointer arithmetics. For data pointers, `*p` and `p[0]` doesn't really make any difference, however.

Comment: You're correct however someone answered before you so I marked them as correct.

Comment: @Ge0rges Yep I know. That's actually a [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/350567) on this site :)

Answer (score 1):

`*pointer` and `pointer[0]` are exactly the same in C.  But that means that `*fib_sequence[i]` is the same as `fib_sequence[i][0]`, which is NOT the same as `fib_sequence[0][i]` (unless `i` happens to be 0).  Suffix operators in C are all higher precedence than prefix operators.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `int *fib[]` is parsed as `int* (fib)[]`; that is, an unbounded array of `int*`. You probably meant `int (*fib)[]`: a pointer to an unbounded array of integers. Once you make that change, your first example [no longer compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/AJeSHy) (as it should), but `(*fib_sequence)[i]` and `fib_sequence[0][i]` both work (also as they should).

However, `*fib_sequence = malloc(sizeof(int[count]))` is now an error, because you can't assign an array value. That means that you would have to move `malloc` outside of the function, or give up the `int (*fib)[]` syntax and use `int** fib` instead.